# ChangeCursor and getItemViewType java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I am Using Cursor Adapters to populate my listview but when I am changing the Cursor this will gives the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
package me.nkkumawat.chatzzz.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import me.nkkumawat.chatzzz.R;


public class ChatAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Cursor cursor;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_chat, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tv_message = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);
        TextView tv_message_from = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_from);

        String body = cursor.getString(1);
        tv_message_from.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        tv_message.setText(body);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position < getCount()) {
            return position;
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
2019-03-22 11:52:40.860 10887-10887/me.nkkumawat.chatzzz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: me.nkkumawat.chatzzz, PID: 10887
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=172; index=172
    at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6851)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1689)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2354)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2081)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6348)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I want to prevent the state of listview. If I am remove the getItemViewType method then on scroll listview changes and looks bad. I want to prevent the state of Listview.
Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to use cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_HERE_IN_STRING));

Comment: not helping this